# What syntax do most experienced Ruby programmers prefer?

Tags: ruby, syntax, coding-style

In Ruby, you can omit the parentheses on method calls and also omit the return keyword in methods, as returning the last statement is implicit. For the experienced Ruby programmers, what is the primary trend you've seen and used regarding parentheses usage for method calls and return statements at the end of methods?

Comment: When in doubt, use parentheses.

Comment: The question is not clear. Is it asking whether omitting parentheses is a trend or not doing so is a trend, and omitting return is a trend or not doing so is a trend? If so, then that is a question with very limited answer: one in two possibilities.

Comment: Therefore it should be a very simple question to answer, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always include parenthesis when it clearly aids in code readability and omit when it doesn't add clarity.

```
def foo bar
  string = "hello from foo method"
  bar #omit return keyword
end
foo "cookie" 

def foo(bar)
  string = "hello from foo method"
  return bar
end
foo("cookie")
```

Both method defs/calls are acceptable. I prefer the first as parans clutter up code in my opinion and most in the Ruby community would agree. However you use, what you're comfortably with, **but just keep it consistent**.

`bar` is returned no need to use `return` keyword. The last statement executed in a method will always be returned.

**Links included for further learning:**

- Ruby Style Guide:
  https://github.com/styleguide/ruby
- Ruby Usage Guide:
  http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml

Neither are official Ruby documents but both can be referenced for general consensus of how to write and format your code as per community preferences.

Comment: Link-only answers are fragile, as links tend to go bad.  Would you please consider embedding in your answer the relevant extracts from those links?

Comment: @WayneConrad Updated my answer as per requested.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was just what I was looking for.  I guess some people had issues with my question however my background is Java and I want to learn the proper way to organize my Ruby code for myself and others who I might collaborate with.